# HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#153)

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, heap-memory

CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer.

Yet I'm not sure where I'm writing past the heap. The error occurs as soon as I call a delete[] data;

Data is a pointer to an array of doubles. I've tried to get rid of some unnecessary code.

Source code:

```
#include "sequence2.h"
using namespace main_savitch_4;

// CONSTRUCTORS and DESTRUCTORS

// The default sequence constructor
// Purpose: To create an instance of a sequence
// Parameters: (int) initial_capacity
// Returns: None
sequence::sequence(int initial_capacity)
{
    // Allocate memory for the new sequence
    data = new value_type[capacity];
    // Set the capacity to the passed in capacity
    capacity = initial_capacity;
    // Set used to 0 because there are currently no objects in the sequence
    used = 0;
    // Set the current index to the 0 for the first item
    current_index = 0;
}

// The sequence copy constructor
// Purpose: To create a deep copy of a sequence
// Parameters: A source sequence
// Returns: None
sequence::sequence(const sequence& source)
{
    // Allocate memory to the new sequence using the capacity of the passed sequence
    data = new value_type[source.capacity];
    // Set the capacity to the passed capacity
    capacity = source.capacity;
    // Set used to the number of used indexes in the previous sequence
    used = source.used;
    // Set the current_index to the index of the passed sequence
    current_index = source.current_index;

    // Copy all data from the passed sequence into the new sequence
    for (int i = 0; i < used; i++)
    {
        data[i] = source.data[i];
    }
}

// The default sequence destructor
// Purpose: To de-allocate memory for a sequence
// Parameters: None
// Returns: None
sequence::~sequence()
{
    // De-allocate dynamic memory
    delete[] data;
}

// MODIFICATION MEMBER FUNCTIONS

// The overload assignment operator function
// Purpose: To assign a sequence with the data from another sequence
// Parameters: A source sequence
// Returns: None
void sequence::operator=(const sequence& source)
{
    value_type *new_data;

    // Check for possible self-assignment
    if (this == &source)
        return;

    // If the capacity of the source is not equal to the original
    if (capacity != source.capacity)
    {
        // Create a new sequence using the source capacity
        new_data = new value_type[source.capacity];
        // Delete the old sequence
        delete[] data;
        // Assign data pointer to the new sequence
        data = new_data;
        // Set capacity to the new source capacity
        capacity = source.capacity;
    }

    // Set used equal to the source "used"
    used = source.used;

    // Copy data from the source sequence into the new sequence
    for (int i = 0; i < used; i++)
    {
        data[i] = source.data[i];
    }
}

// The resize function
// Purpose: To grow a sequence when necessary
// Parameters: (int) new_capacity
// Returns: None
void sequence::resize(int new_capacity)
{
    // Declare a larger array
    value_type *larger_array;

    if (new_capacity == capacity)
        return; // The allocated memory is already the right size

    if (new_capacity < used)
        new_capacity = used; // Can't allocate less than we are using

    // Dynamically allocate memory for the larger array with the new capacity
    larger_array = new value_type[new_capacity];

    // Copy the data from the old array to the larger array
    for (int i = 0; i < used; i++)
    {
        larger_array[i] = data[i];
    }
    // Delete the old array
    delete[] data;
    // Set the pointer to the larger array
    data = larger_array;
    // Set the capacity to the new capacity
    capacity = new_capacity;
}

// The insert function
// Purpose: To insert an item before the current index
// Parameters: (const value_type&) entry
// Returns: None
void sequence::insert(const value_type& entry)
{
    // If used and capacity are the same, resize the sequence
    if (used == capacity)
        resize(used + 1);

    // If the current index is an item...
    if (is_item())
    {
        // Block of code that moves objects ahead of insert forward
        for (int i = used; i > current_index; i--)
        {
            data[i] = data[i-1];
        }
    }

    // Set the current index to the new entry
    data[current_index] = entry;
    // Increment used because we've added an item
    ++used;
}

// The attach function
// Purpose: To attach an item after the current index
// Parameters: (const value_type&) entry
// Returns: None
void sequence::attach(const value_type& entry)
{
    // If used and capacity are the same, resize the sequence
    if (used == capacity)
        resize(used + 1);

    // If the current index is an item...
    if (is_item())
    {
        // Block of code that moves objects ahead of attach forward
        for (int i = used; i > current_index; i--)
        {
            data[i] = data[i-1];
        }

        // Set the current index to the recently attached item
        ++current_index;
        // Store the entry in the new current index
        data[current_index] = entry;
    }
    else
    {
        // Set the current index to the end of the sequence
        current_index = used;
        // Put that entry into that new index
        data[current_index] = entry;
    }

    // Increment used because we've added an item
    ++used;
}

// CONSTANT MEMBER FUNCTIONS

// The is_item function
// Purpose: To check if the current index contains an item
// Parameters: None
// Returns: None
bool sequence::is_item() const
{
    // If the current index is greater than used, or used is equal to 0
    // there is no current item
    if (current_index >= used || used == 0)
        return false;
    else // otherwise there is a current item
        return true;
}
```

Comment: For starters, in the copy assignment operator you don't copy the `current_index` member variable. Could it be part of your problem?

Comment: I should clarify that I believe the problem exists when I write data to the dynamic sequence in the inset and attach functions.

Comment: Also, try to create the shortest and simplest example causing your problem, and then use a debugger to step through the code line by line to see that it doesn't go out of bounds anywhere.

Comment: @ColinMarshall The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric  Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

LOL, here is the solution

```
sequence::sequence(int initial_capacity)
{
    // Allocate memory for the new sequence
    data = new value_type[**initial_capacity**];
    // Set the capacity to the passed in capacity
    capacity = initial_capacity;
    // Set used to 0 because there are currently no objects in the sequence
    used = 0;
    // Set the current index to the 0 for the first item
    current_index = 0;
```

}

Comment: A good compiler, possibly with extra warnings enabled, would be able to tell you about when you use uninitialized variables.